# PHP echo within a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, echo

So the problem is as follows:
I want to dynamically echo a javascript thing with PHP. This echo needs to be (or work with) another javascript file where the echo'd value is used to call a function when the ID is clicked.

However when the page is loaded and the document.getElementById things are added (and they are correct) when the element is clicked, the console tells me that fplaying is undefined

**PHP File**

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ("We couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db ("dr");
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM songs");
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM songs");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $source = $row ['audiosource'];
    echo "
    document.getElementById('$source').onclick = fplaying
    ";
}
?>
```

**JS File**

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    function fplaying () {
        alert ("test");
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not the right way to do in Php

Comment: Try converting your code and use something like AJAX.

Comment: You don't specify what your problem/difficulty is. You should learn about ajax calls in javascript, you're doing it the wrong way for now.

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant to your question here. Post the rendered HTML and JavaScript. Plus, if you're using jQuery, why are you doing `document.getElementById('$source').onclick = fplaying`?

Comment: Javascript is Client side language where as PHP is server side ,Use it for The same purposes  ! :)

Comment: @j08691 I'm using the document.getElementById thing because I can't get it to work with jquery. And what do you mean with the rendered HTML and Javascript? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @PratikJoshi though rendering Javascript in PHP isn't best approach it isn't impossible to work that way. According to the OP's issue of trying to invoke local-only defined function your assessing of quality of its basic approach won't help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this can be done with `php` and this is probably not the answer you are looking for.But long comments are not recommended so I just posted as an answer.

It is possible to do, I have done when I was new to Web Developments (With ASP.Net), but still this indicates an improper architecture. JavaScript, that you are using, is a client side script and thus should be accompanied with proper AJAX structure to do such thing. Server should only be responsible to send proper response based on request, not dictate how a page should behave on client side.

Some thing like -

```
var play = function(){
    ...//code to play
};

$.ajax({
   url: ..//url to php page
   type: ...
   ...,
   success: function(data){
      ...//data responded by php page
      play();
   },
   error: function(){
   }
});
```

I used syntax for `jQuery`. There are other libraries too.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. Try this.

```
echo " <script> ";
  echo "document.getElementById('$source').onclick = fplaying ";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: Sir, Is this correct approach ? :) Javascript is Client side language where as PHP is server side ,Use it for The same purposes ! :)

Comment: @Sreenath The problem is that when clicking the element (with the echo'd ID) the console says that fplaying is undefined

Comment: @NealVDV did you check my answer? it contains the solution to the problem you describe

Answer (score 1):

I don't think

```
 document.getElementById('$source').onclick = fplaying
```

will find the function as `fplaying` is undefined.

Try:

```
var fplaying = function() {
    alert ("test");
}
```

instead of

```
function fplaying () {
    alert ("test");
}
```

Comment: Sir, Is this correct approach ? :) Javascript is Client side language where as PHP is server side ,Use it for The same purposes ! :)

Comment: @PratikJoshi I personally, would not use this approach :)  I'm merely attempting to help the op debug his code

Comment: @andrew Like you said it is undefinedbut. When following your suggestion it does not say undefined but the function still does not executed. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @NealVDV Its probably due to the order, Ie document.getElementById..... is being sent to the browser before the function is defined. If I were you Id go back to jQuery bu use `$.on()` then elements loaded in the future will be bound to the function

Comment: @andrew Your advised approaches for declaring a function are identical from a semantic point of view. In either case there will be a local variable called `fplaying` of type `function`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, from what I understand of your problem:
Your php creates a html file that has an element with id="the value of $source" and you want it to play a sound on click.

If you want to create a piece of javascript like you did, you could try:
    echo ""
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

```
    $source = $row ['audiosource'];

    echo "
    document.getElementById('$source').onclick = fplaying()
    ";
}
echo "</script>"
```

That should make the browser recognize the script as javascript and execute it. Make sure this is printed to the html *after* the part of the page with the elements you're referring to is printed to the html. Otherwise the script might run before the relevant part of the page is loaded in the browser.

Comment: Sir, Is this correct approach ? :) Javascript is Client side language where as PHP is server side ,Use it for The same purposes ! :)

Comment: It is a perfectly fine approach. You use PHP for the serverside processing and generate client-specific javascript code based on information that is only available on server side. That being said, it might not be the best approach here (based on the info here, I'd personally make a more generic javascript and add the necessary information to the html element in an attribute and have the javascript retrieve that). However, the question asker should have more info than me to decide the best approach.

Comment: @HolySquirrel Even when I put this after the script tags of the js file that holds the function, it still shows undefined in the console. Thanks for your response already!

Comment: Okay, also check out cepharum's answer for your javascript. Check the generated page with view source in the browser (or something similar) and make sure that the function fplaying is defined before this piece of javascript. (also made a slight edit to my answer 'cause I think I made a mistake)

Answer (score 1):

As in the JS you are printing through PHP only sets the onclick event for an element with that ID which exists somewhere else on the page I think. So, much better way of doing this would be define a class in that clickable item

```
<button id='<?php echo $source; ?>' class='click-me'>Click Me</button>
```

Then in JS use this:

```
$('.click-me').on('click',function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your declaration of fplaying() is delayed and in addition its locally defined, only.

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    function fplaying () {
         alert ("test");
    }
});
```

In that code fplaying is dropped as soon as the outer function has finished. Try binding that fplaying to your window instead.

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    window.fplaying = function() {
         alert ("test");
    };
});
```

To illustrate this additionally:

```
function a() {
    function fplaying() {
        alert("Hi");
    }
    fplaying();
}
a();
```

will display alert box.

```
function a() {
    function fplaying() {
        alert("Hi");
    }
}
a();
fplaying();
```

won't show alert box for fplaying() is visible in scope of a(), only, and **thus it's `undefined` as in your case**.

```
function a() {
    window.fplaying = function() {
        alert("Hi");
    };
}
a();
fplaying();
```

will show alert box for now fplaying() is declared as method of object window more or less serving as global scope, too.

For it's delayed using `$(function() { ... });` make sure invoking code as rendered by PHP isn't running before document has loaded. But that doesn't seem to be an issue according to your spare information on context.

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong when outputting the PHP file (currently just in a <script type="text/javascript"><?php include ('phpfile.php')</script>

Comment: Well, there are little opportunities to help you out further on without you providing more information on how these sources of Javascript interact with each other. Try providing skeletons of HTML file integrating that JS code echoed by PHP and that JS code declaring fplaying ... nevertheless *declaring fplaying() the way you do inside of a function makes it visible inside that function, only.*

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have a collection, coming from a db query: `$collection` and consists of associative arrays, with a unique `id`

Now, you are obviously going to display these objects and ask for a user to do something with them, your fplay function. What you must do, is echo whichever parts of the items you need and somehow pass in the html the item id.

So, the php part which will construct your html would be something like:

```
 echo "<ul>";
 $id = $item['id'];
 foreach ($collection as $item){
   echo '<li><a onclick="return fplaying(' + $id + ')" href="#" class="btn"></li>';
 }
 echo "</ul>";
```

Then, your js function would use the id as a parameter and do whatever you need:

```
function fplaying (id) {
  alert ("your id is " + id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$source = $row ['audiosource'];
echo '<div id="'.$source['id'].'" class="sourceDiv">'.$source['name'].'</div>';
```

then go to your js file and add this --you don't have to do that in php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sourceDiv').click(function(){alert($(this).attr('id'))});

});
```